# npm revert and publish and old npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I published an npm package and everything was working fine. I then made an update and republished and it has broken. I had not updated it in a year so I have forgotten the build process, and looks like I have made a mistake in the build. In the meantime I want to publish an older stable version. does anyone know how to revert and publish an old version of the package?

I have tried to reset the commit to an older one and publish that but that doesn't seem to work, unless it is perhaps a caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can not republish the older version but you can delete the newer version which will automatically rollback it to the previous version.

```
npm unpublish <package-name>@<version>
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry

Comment: Getting error- 405 Method Not Allowed - You can no longer unpublish this package. `Failed criteria: has dependent packages in the registry`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. NPM does not allow unpublishing after the leftpad incident, all you can do is fixing the issues/revert the changes and publish an [incremented version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) of the package.

Comment: Further to that, consider pushing a temporary 'newer' version that is actually the older version.

Comment: I did push an older version - so strange - it's not working! it's too early for this kind of stress :-D